# Find $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2$.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

> $$\begin{align}\dfrac{a^2}{2^2 - 1^2} + \dfrac{b^2}{4^2 - 1^2} + \dfrac{c^2}{6^2 - 1^2} + \dfrac{d^2}{8^2 - 1^2} &= \dfrac{a^2}{2^2 - 3^2} + \dfrac{b^2}{4^2 - 3^2} + \dfrac{c^2}{6^2 - 3^2} + \dfrac{d^2}{8^2 - 3^2}
> \\&= \dfrac{a^2}{2^2 - 5^2} + \dfrac{b^2}{4^2 - 5^2} + \dfrac{c^2}{6^2 - 5^2} + \dfrac{d^2}{8^2 - 5^2} \\ &= \dfrac{a^2}{2^2 - 7^2} + \dfrac{b^2}{4^2 - 7^2} + \dfrac{c^2}{6^2 - 7^2} + \dfrac{d^2}{8^2 - 7^2}
> \\ &= 1\end{align}$$
> Find $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2$.

**My Approach:**

I tried forming Linear equations by taking $a^2=x, b^2=y, c^2=z, d^2=w$

Then I obtained

$\dfrac{x}{3}+\dfrac{y}{15}+\dfrac{z}{35}+\dfrac{w}{63}=1$

$\dfrac{x}{-5}+\dfrac{y}{7}+\dfrac{z}{27}+\dfrac{w}{55}=1$

$\dfrac{x}{-21}+\dfrac{y}{-9}+\dfrac{z}{11}+\dfrac{w}{39}=1$

$\dfrac{x}{-45}+\dfrac{y}{-33}+\dfrac{z}{-13}+\dfrac{w}{15}=1$

After solving with [www.wolframalpha.com](http://www.wolframalpha.com) I obtained the result

$w=\frac{6435}{256}$, $x=\frac{315}{512}$, $y= \frac{693}{256}$, $z=\frac{3861}{512}$

Which lead me $x+y+z+w=36$ that is $a^2+b^2+c^2+z^2=36$

**But how to solve this question without any calculator or online tools because it was asked to a $11th$ class student**

[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=systems+of+equations+calculator&assumption=%22FSelect%22+-%3E+%7B%7B%22SolveSystemOf4EquationsCalculator%22%7D%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22SolveSystemOf4EquationsCalculator%22%2C+%22equation1%22%7D+-%3E%22x%2F3%2By%2F15%2Bz%2F35%2Bw%2F63%3D1%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22SolveSystemOf4EquationsCalculator%22%2C+%22equation2%22%7D+-%3E%22-x%2F5%2By%2F7%2Bz%2F27%2Bw%2F55%3D1%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22SolveSystemOf4EquationsCalculator%22%2C+%22equation3%22%7D+-%3E%22-x%2F21-y%2F9%2Bz%2F11%2Bw%2F39%3D1%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22SolveSystemOf4EquationsCalculator%22%2C+%22equation4%22%7D+-%3E%22-x%2F45-y%2F33-z%2F13%2Bw%2F15%3D1%22)

Comment: I am confused.  What was the original question that was given to you?

Comment: It's at the top. There's a condition with many equals signs and the question is to find $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$.

Comment: yeah, not a fun thing to solve on an exam. had to do similar things on exams in freshman year in college. pretty sure I got it wrong. we were offered to use matlab but I declined like a moron. anyway, i'd have done it your way, by hand, with a lot of arithmetic. maybe use Cramers rule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We write down the following polynomial:
\begin{eqnarray}
f(x) &=& (x - 2^2)(x - 4^2)(x - 6^2)(x - 8^2)\\
&+& a^2(x - 4^2)(x - 6^2)(x - 8^2)\\
&+& b^2(x - 2^2)(x - 6^2)(x - 8^2)\\
&+& c^2(x - 2^2)(x - 4^2)(x - 8^2)\\
&+& d^2(x - 2^2)(x - 4^2)(x - 6^2).
\end{eqnarray}
The given conditions then imply that $f(1^2) = f(3^2) = f(5^2) = f(7^2) = 0$.

However, $f(x)$ is a monic polynomial of degree $4$. Therefore we have $$f(x) = (x - 1^2)(x - 3^2)(x - 5^2)(x - 7^2).$$
It only remains to evaluate $f(x)$ at $x = 2^2, 4^2, 6^2, 8^2$ respectively to get values of $a^2, b^2, c^2, d^2$.

---

As suggested in the comments, one can look at the coefficient before $x^3$ to get the value of $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2$ without doing much calculation.

Comment: Ingenious, +1. But shouldn't the first term in your original polynomial have the opposite sign?

Comment: @Troposphere In the problem statement, it was $2^2 - x$ etc. in the denominator, and I moved them to the other side so that they become $x - 2^2$ etc.

Comment: I see. Now, the values you get out of evaluating the polynomial at, say $2^2$ is for example $a^2=\frac{f(2^2)}{(2^2-4^2)(2^2-6^2)(2^2-8^2)}$ which makes $a^2,b^2,c^2,d^2$ come out as the scary fractions in the OP's solution. Is there a nice way to see they have to sum to the integer $36$?

Comment: @Troposphere Calculate the $x^3 $ term. you get it directly.

Comment: @Troposphere This might look scary, but actually not quite, because numbers of the form $u^2 - v^2$ can be decomposed as $(u + v)(u - v)$, and we may have many cancellations between the left and right hand sides, so that the actual calculation is doable by hand.

Comment: @Troposphere: I was just thinking that too. To cut down the arithmetic you can compare the coefficient of $x^3$ in the definition of $f(x)$ with the coefficient of $x^3$ in the factorisation to get $a^2+b^2+c^2 + d^2 = (4 + 16 + 36 + 64) - (1 + 9 + 25 + 49)$.

Comment: @CalvinLin Good point, thanks for that!